# Disable JQuery script by window size

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

How can I disable "external.js" from loading when the viewport falls under 1100px as stated in the conditional CSS tag?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:1100px)" href="style/master1100.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:700px)" href="style/master700.css">
</head>

<body>
...
</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't, but you can wrap the code in external.js in a condition that checks the windows width on pageload.

Comment: What should happen if the view-port starts as 1101px, and then resized to 1099px?

Comment: The JQuery script "external.js" shouldn't load.

Comment: Once load it, you have to live with it, you could change how it affects the page if resized though.